# PermissionError in Hugging Face Spaces when Deploying FastAPI App: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'app.csv'

Tags: docker, fastapi, huggingface

This is the dockerfile I have in the hugging face space:

```
# Use the base Docker image
FROM circulartextapp/lastread

# Set the working directory to /app (if needed)
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Example CMD (modify as needed)
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "7860"]
```

I'm encountering a PermissionError when deploying my FastAPI app on Hugging Face Spaces. The application works flawlessly in the local container, but when deployed on the Hugging Face Hub, I face the following error

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 408, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1106, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 274, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 191, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/app/main.py", line 80, in generate_app_csv_and_run_aa_backend
    with open(CSV_FILE_PATH0, mode='w') as csv_file:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'app.csv'
```

this is the fast api code i am using

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Form
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, JSONResponse, FileResponse
import subprocess
import json
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse, HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()



CSV_FILE_PATH = 'slideinfo.csv'
CSV_FILE_PATH0 = 'app.csv'
PYTHON_SCRIPT_PATH0 = 'AAmain.py'
PYTHON_SCRIPT_PATH = 'AGmain.py'
PYTHON_INTERPRETER = 'python'


# Set up static files
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="."), name="static")


# Route to serve timing_script.js
@app.get("/timing_script.js", response_class=FileResponse)
async def read_timing_script_js():
    return FileResponse("static/timing_script.js")

# Route to serve batch.csv
@app.get("/batch.csv", response_class=FileResponse)
async def read_batch_csv():
    return FileResponse("static/batch.csv")

# Route to serve wav.wav
@app.get("/wav.wav", response_class=FileResponse)
async def read_wav():
    return FileResponse("wav.wav")

# Route to serve wav3.wav
@app.get("/wav3.wav", response_class=FileResponse)
async def read_wav3():
    return FileResponse("wav3.wav")

# HTML Response for the root endpoint
@app.get("/", response_class=FileResponse)
async def read_root():
    return FileResponse("static/index.html")

# Endpoint for generating CSV and running the backend script
@app.post("/generate_csv_and_run_backend")
async def generate_csv_and_run_backend(
    low: str = Form(...),
    mid: str = Form(...),
    high: str = Form(...),
):
    csv_data = f"Low Option,Mid Option,High Option\n{low}, {mid}, {high}\n"

    with open(CSV_FILE_PATH, mode='w') as csv_file:
        csv_file.write(csv_data)

    process = subprocess.Popen([PYTHON_INTERPRETER, PYTHON_SCRIPT_PATH, CSV_FILE_PATH], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    if process.returncode != 0:
        print(stderr)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Error running the backend script")

    return JSONResponse(content={"message": "CSV file generated and backend script executed successfully"})

# Endpoint for generating app.csv and running AAmain script
@app.post("/generate_app_csv_and_run_aa_backend")
async def generate_app_csv_and_run_aa_backend(user_input: dict):
    app_csv_data = f"User Input\n{user_input['userInput']}\n"

    with open(CSV_FILE_PATH0, mode='w') as csv_file:
        csv_file.write(app_csv_data)

    process = subprocess.Popen([PYTHON_INTERPRETER, PYTHON_SCRIPT_PATH0, CSV_FILE_PATH0], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    if process.returncode != 0:
        print(stderr)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Error running the AAmain backend script")

    # Return the generated CSV file as a response
    return FileResponse(CSV_FILE_PATH0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

This is how the image looks inside a container
[docker image working inside a container container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OizxZ.png)